# Empty space above iphone app content

Tags: iphone, ios

I am completely new to Iphone App Dev and I have made a test interface that when run has an empty space above the content (even the status bar where the time and battery meter is) 
Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Notice the Big black space? What is this?

FYI I also tested it on my iphone with ios7 and it does the same thing...

Comment: There are two iPhone screen sizes, the titlebar of the simulator says its a 4 inch screen. Read up on the platform a bit so you are aware of the different hardware specs you can support (or not).

Comment: Ty I thought it had something to do with that. Where would be a good start for reading up on compatibility for iOS interfaces?

Answer (score 2):

This was happen because of your view size, Your view height is `480 (iPhone4/4s or iPod)`, but you execute this application in `iPhone 5 simulator` and the size of it is `(568)` thats why this was happen.

Either you need to execute your application in `3.5 inch simulator` or set your view according to iPhone 5 `(568 size view)`

Answer (score 2):

You are running application in 4" simulator and if you have not included splash screen for 4" with name Default-568h@2x.png in your application it will remain as it is.

You should include Default-568h@2x.png file for supportingi both 3.5" and 4" display size. For beginners [this is the best tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33150/how-to-update-your-apps-for-the-4-inch-iphone-5-display) for supporting both screen size resolution.

**Note:**
For the tutorial you need to know autolayout constraint as well so please read that first.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have not supported your app for iPhone 5.

You can either use [**Autoresizing Mask**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout.html) or [**Auto Layout**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853) to adjust your UI components for different screens.

If you are using iOS >= 6.0  then autolayout would be a good option to choose.
[Here is another good guide for this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2)